# How to attach a method to the event of closing down the python application?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

I need assistance on the following problem that I am facing.

I have a Tkinter UI which have 3 buttons (Register, Lock the folders and unlock the folders). There is a cross button on the top right corner as in all the applications. Refer to the following snapshot.

So the idea is that when user unlocks his folder through this UI, and then press the cross button, that folder and all the folder's content which might have been opened by the user, must be closed down.

[image: UI window snapshot]

Below is the Code for closing down the folders.

```
def lockFolder_crossButton():
    if userName.get()!='':
      answer_folder = getFolderName()

     #####check if the folder has already been locked or not!!!!*********
      if os.path.exists('./secretFolder/'+userName.get()):
          LockFolder.lockFolders(userName.get(), answer_folder)

    global timer_active
    timer_active = 'no'
    window.destroy()
```

The above code is present in a class "openApplication.py" which is started when this application runs.

The following code of class Facelock.launch.pyw imports this class.

```
#!python2.7
import sys, os
scriptdir, script = os.path.split(__file__)
pkgdir = os.path.join(scriptdir, 'pkgs')
sys.path.insert(0, pkgdir)
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = pkgdir + os.pathsep + os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH', '')

# APPDATA should always be set, but in case it isn't, try user home
# If none of APPDATA, HOME, USERPROFILE or HOMEPATH are set, this will fail.
appdata = os.environ.get('APPDATA', None) or os.path.expanduser('~')

if 'pythonw' in sys.executable:
    # Running with no console - send all stdstream output to a file.
    kw = {'errors': 'replace'} if (sys.version_info[0] >= 3) else {}
    sys.stdout = sys.stderr = open(os.path.join(appdata, script+'.log'), 'w', **kw)
else:
    # In a console. But if the console was started just for this program, it
    # will close as soon as we exit, so write the traceback to a file as well.
    def excepthook(etype, value, tb):
        "Write unhandled exceptions to a file and to stderr."
        import traceback
        traceback.print_exception(etype, value, tb)
        with open(os.path.join(appdata, script+'.log'), 'w') as f:
            traceback.print_exception(etype, value, tb, file=f)
    sys.excepthook = excepthook



if __name__ == '__main__':
    from openApplication import self
    self()
```

The following code is the snapshot related to the cross button of the UI window and the method calling after that button is pressed.

```
window = Tk()
window.title("FaceLock")
window.geometry('800x800')

####some piece of code

window.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', lockFolder_crossButton)

window.mainloop()
```

The following is the error that I am facing.

[image]

So is there any idea what is the issue here?
And how do you suggest to approach the problem?

Below is the code for openApplication.py

```
from Tkinter import *
import detector as dt
import os
import dataSetGenerator as generate
import trainData as train
import storeDictionary as save
from subprocess import Popen
import random
import pickle
import CheckFace as checkFace
import createAndHide as CreateFolder
from threading import Timer
import LockFolder, UnlockFolder


window = Tk()
window.title("FaceLock")
window.geometry('800x800')

empCode=StringVar()
userName=StringVar()
duration=StringVar()
errorLabel=Label(text="")

remaining=10
timer_active='no'
sub_folder='no'
locked=False

usertimer=StringVar()

timerLabel=Label(text="")
timerlabelcountdown=Label(text="")


def saveDictionary():
  errorLabel.config(text='')


  if userName.get() == '':
      errorLabel.config(text="User name cant be left blank")
      return
  if empCode.get() == '':
      errorLabel.config(text=" Employee code Cant be left blank")
      return
  try:
      val = int(empCode.get())
  except ValueError:
      errorLabel.config(text="Enter a valid employee ID")
      return
  if duration.get() == '':
      errorLabel.config(text="Duration cant be left blank")
      return
  try:
      val = int(duration.get())
  except ValueError:
      errorLabel.config(text="Enter a valid Duration")
      return
  if int(duration.get())<1 or int(duration.get())>61:
      errorLabel.config(text="Enter between 0 and 60 min")
      return

  if(save.findName(empCode.get())!='not' or save.findEmpCode(userName.get())!='not'):
      errorLabel.config(text="User with this employee id or user name has already been registered")
      return
  flag=checkFace.checkFace()

  if(flag==False):
      errorLabel.config(text="This face is already a known face")
      return

  range_start = 10 ** (4 - 1)
  range_end = (10 ** 4 ) - 1
  rndmnumber= str(random.randint(range_start, range_end))

  if len(duration.get()) == 1:
    foldername=rndmnumber+'0'+duration.get()+empCode.get()
    print "employee code ="+empCode.get()+" username for this is "+userName.get()
  else:
    foldername = rndmnumber +duration.get() + empCode.get()
  dict={empCode.get():str(userName.get())}
  save.store(dict)
  dict2={userName.get():foldername}
  save.storeFolder(dict2)

  generateData()
  trainData()


def recogniseFace():
    flag=dt.detector()
    print flag
    window.destroy

print empCode.get()

def generateData():
    generate.generateDataSet(empCode.get())

def trainData():
    pickle_in_foldername = open('./utilities/folderdictionary.pickle','rb')
    dictionary_foldername = pickle.load(pickle_in_foldername)
    answer_folder = dictionary_foldername[userName.get()]
    answer_folder=str(answer_folder)
    CreateFolder.createFolder(answer_folder)
    #Popen("./utilities/createAndHide.bat "+ userName.get() + " "+answer_folder)
    flag=train.trainDataSet(empCode.get())
    if(flag==True):
        errorLabel.config(text="trained")
    else:
        errorLabel.config(text="not trained")



def defineRegister(flag,button):

    if(flag):
        userLabel = Label(text="enter your username")
        userLabel.grid()

        userEntry = Entry(textvariable=userName)
        userEntry.grid()

        empLabel = Label(text="enter your employeeCode")
        empLabel.grid()

        Entry(textvariable=empCode).grid()
        Label(text="Duration for which Folder should be opened ").grid()
        Entry(textvariable=duration).grid()
        button = Button(text="DataSet Generation", command=lambda: lambda: saveDictionary()).grid()


def checkTime():
    if getFolderName()!='not':
        duration=getFolderName()[4:6]
        return int(duration)



def lockFolder():
    global locked
    locked = True
    #print 'here'
    global timer_active
    timer_active = 'no'
    timerlabelcountdown.config(text='')
    timerLabel.config(text='')
    answer_folder = getFolderName()
    #closeSubFolders(userName.get())

    #os.system('nircmd win close title "%s"' %userName.get())

    LockFolder.lockFolders(userName.get(),answer_folder)

    #Popen("./utilities/lockFolder.bat "+userName.get()+" "+answer_folder)
    global sub_folder
    sub_folder = 'yes'
    #user.configure(state=NORMAL)
    unlockFolder_button.config(state=NORMAL)
    userEntry.config(state=NORMAL)
    empCodeEntry.config(state=NORMAL)
    register_button.config(state=NORMAL)
    lockFolder_button.config(state=DISABLED)
    duration_box.config(state=NORMAL)


def getFolderName():
    checkName = userName.get()
    pickle_in_foldername = open(
        './utilities/folderdictionary.pickle',
        'rb')
    try:
        dictionary_foldername = pickle.load(pickle_in_foldername)
        answer_folder = dictionary_foldername[checkName]
    except:
        answer_folder = 'not'
    return answer_folder


def lockFolder_crossButton():

    if userName.get() != '':
        answer_folder = getFolderName()

        #####check if the folder has already been locked or not!!!!*********
        if os.path.exists('./secretFolder/' + userName.get()):
            LockFolder.lockFolders(userName.get(), answer_folder)

        # Popen("./utilities/lockFolder.bat " + userName.get() + " " + answer_folder)
    global timer_active
    timer_active = 'no'
    window.destroy()


def unlockFolder(checkName,answer_folder):
    #Popen("./utilities/openFolder.bat " + checkName + " " + answer_folder)
    UnlockFolder.unlock(checkName,answer_folder)
    userEntry.config(state=DISABLED)
    empCodeEntry.config(state=DISABLED)
    unlockFolder_button.config(state=DISABLED)
    lockFolder_button.config(state=NORMAL)
    #duration.config(state=DISABLED)

def checkLock():

    if locked==False:
        lockFolder()

def countdown():
    global timer_active
    global remaining
    if remaining <= 0 and timer_active == 'yes':
        timerlabelcountdown.config(text="time's up!")
    elif timer_active == 'yes':
        timerlabelcountdown.config(text="%d" % remaining)
        remaining = remaining - 1
        timer = Timer(1, countdown)
        timer.start()


def recogniseFace():
    locked=False
    lockFolder_button.config(state=NORMAL)
    duration_box.config(state=DISABLED)
    register_button.config(state=DISABLED)
    errorLabel.config(text='')
    timerlabelcountdown.config(text='')
    if userName.get() == '':
        errorLabel.config( text='User Name can not be left blank')
        return
    if save.findEmpCode(userName.get()) == 'not':
        errorLabel.config(text='Please register yourself')
        duration_box.config(state=NORMAL)
        register_button.config(state=NORMAL)
        return
    final_time = checkTime()
    if usertimer.get() != '':
        try:
            if int(usertimer.get()) < 1 or int(usertimer.get()) > 61:
                 errorLabel.config( text='Enter between 0 and 60 min')
                 return
            final_time = int(usertimer.get())
        except ValueError:
            errorLabel.config( text='Enter a valid duration')
            return
    flag=dt.detector()
    if flag==False:
        errorLabel.config(text='Could not recognize you')
        return
    checkName=userName.get()
    answer_folder = getFolderName()
    print "checkName"+checkName+" flag="+flag
    if(checkName==flag):
        global timer_active
        timer_active='yes'
        timerLabel.config(text='Session is active')
        global remaining
        remaining=final_time*60
        countdown()
        unlockFolder(checkName,answer_folder)
        timer = Timer(final_time * 60, checkLock)
        timer.start()


Label(text="Welcome to the admin Screen").grid()
userLabel = Label(text="enter your username")
userLabel.grid()

userEntry = Entry(textvariable=userName)
userEntry.grid()



empLabel = Label(text="enter your employeeCode!")
empLabel.grid()
#empLabel.config(state=DISABLED)

empCodeEntry=Entry(textvariable=empCode)
empCodeEntry.grid()
#empCodeEntry.config(state=DISABLED)

durationLabel=Label(text="Duration for which Folder should be opened ")
durationLabel.grid()


duration_box=Entry(textvariable=duration)
duration_box.grid()
duration_box.config(state=NORMAL)

register_button=Button(text="Registeration",command=saveDictionary)
register_button.grid()

lockFolder_button=Button(text="Lock My Folder Please!",command=lockFolder)
lockFolder_button.grid()
lockFolder_button.config(state=DISABLED)
unlockFolder_button=Button(text="Unlock My Folder",command=recogniseFace)
unlockFolder_button.grid()

close_Application_Button=Button(text="Close Application",command=lambda:lockFolder_crossButton())
close_Application_Button.grid()

errorLabel.grid()
timerLabel.grid()
timerlabelcountdown.grid()

#window.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', lockFolder_crossButton)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: The code after `window.mainloop()` is executed when the user clicks the `X` button.

Comment: does `openApplication.py` have a function or class named `self`? That seems highly unlikely. Your comment says _"The following code instantiates this class."_, but it doesn't instantiate anything. It merely imports something.

Comment: @BryanOakley no openApplication does not have self.
the self is the code written in the class made by pynsist installer.
I am updating the question with this class's code as well. Kindly check that too for your reference.

Comment: @rioV8 can i override this method?

Comment: if `openApplication.py` doesn't export something named `self`, you can't expect to be able to import something named `self`.

Comment: @BryanOakley But then everything is working fine. openApplication is opening up the folders, closing down the folders and renaming the folders and hiding them when Lock button is pressed but the error is coming only when cross button is pressed.

Comment: What do you think `from openApplication import self` is doing? From the code you have shown us the file `openApplication.py` does not contain a `self()` function.

Comment: As always here on SO. First make a running example that shows the behavior. Do not copy and paste a few parts of your large application. Most likely during this creation you find the cause of the problem because the example behaves nicely.

Comment: @Mike-SMT self() function refers to the "python openApplication.exe"...
Thats what will happen if you try to run any example in python

Comment: Not sure I understand. Unless you have written a function, class or method inside of `openApplication.py` then `self()` will do nothing but cause the exact error you have there.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I can assure you that there is no error related to this!

Comment: Its right there in your screenshot. `import error: cannot import self`. That error is very specifically telling you that no method exist called `self()` inside of `openApplications.py`. Unless you want to show more of that py file there is nothing else we can do to help.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I have added the code for openApplication.py also. 
The code works properly in the first run, but it stuck at LockFolder_crossButton()

Comment: I will take a look when I get to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code. Indention needs to be fixed, `recogniseFace()` has been defined twice in your code so you need to rename one of these functions and your import will not work due to no `self()` method existing in `openApplication.py`.

I believe your main problem is here.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from openApplication import self
    self()
```

You are trying to import `self` from `openApplication.py` however you have not defined any method with the name self so python is unable to import self. That said you should never use self for anything other than its intended use inside of a class.

I believe what you should do is place your code inside of a function and then import that function.

In your `openApplication.py` file place all your code inside of a function and call it what you want. I think `main()` would work fine here.

Next in `Facelock.launch.pyw` replace your `if __name__ == '__main__':` section with this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from openApplication import main
    main()
```

This will correct the import error.